# Is there a way to transfer from Phuket to Ko Phi Phi if you miss the 2:30pm ferry?

Tags: transportation, thailand, ferries, phuket, phi-phi

We will be arriving in Phuket after a tour at about 5pm.  Is there any way to make a transfer to a resort on the eastern side of Ko Phi Phi on the same day?

Costs will be split amongst 5 so a private transfer might be reasonable.  For comparison, the ferry will cost 580 THB each = 2,900 THB.  This will be in July.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, but you would have to charter your own speedboat, which would be stupidly expensive: quotes on the net vary from 8000 baht for a privately negotiated transfer to 15000 baht (!) to getting the Holiday Inn to pick you up in their own boat.  Staying another night and taking the ferry across the next day will thus almost certainly be cheaper.

In addition, the feasibility and cost of this will depend on weather conditions, and the crossing will be actively dangerous if your departure is delayed for any reason and you end up doing it at night: those speedboats are *fast* and you're screwed if you hit anything in the dark.

Also, Destination Air used to offer a seaplane shuttle for 5000 baht/seat, but this stopped running a few years ago.

Comment: I always hated the sea, and now after I read `fast and you're screwed if you hit anything in the dark` I hate the sea even more! can you imagine in the middle of the sea and dark! and I paid 500$ to have that!!!

Comment: As it transpired, a storm rolled in at around 4pm that day and I was glad not to be contemplating a speedboat ride.  Come morning the ocean was calm and the ferry comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

Wait and take the ferry is the best option.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's the best, the cost, maybe some further details? This answer gets flagged as low quality currently, so we always try to improve answers.